# how can I download selective date range files from S3 bucket based on given date range like 08th aug to 15 Aug using AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, s3-bucket

I am able to filter a particular date's data but not the date range data.
Like 12-09-2019 to 15-09-2019 using AWS CLI

eg. to filter 2019 year's data i am using 
--recursive --exclude "*" --include "*2019*"

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [mcve] and see [ask] to maximize the chance to obtain a valuable feedback

Answer (score 5):

You will need to use the s3api to handle the query which uses the [JMESPath](https://jmespath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) syntax

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket BUCKET --query "Contents[?(LastModified>='2019-09-12' && LastModified<='2019-09-15')].Key"
```

You can also specify time as well

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket BUCKET --query "Contents[?(LastModified>='2019-09-12T12:00:00.00Z' && LastModified<='2019-09-15T12:00:00.00Z')].Key"
```

The downside to this approach is that it must list every object and perform the query. For large buckets if you can limit to a prefix it will speed up your search.

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket BUCKET --prefix PREFIX --query "Contents[?(LastModified>='2019-09-12T12:00:00.00Z' && LastModified<='2019-09-15T12:00:00.00Z')].Key"
```

And if your primary lookup is by date then look to store the objects in date/time sort order as you can use the prefix option to speed up your searches. A couple of examples.

```
prefix/20190615T041019Z.json.gz
2019/06/15/T041019Z.json.gz
```

This will